# MySQL InnoDB hash index optimizing

Tags: mysql, optimization

I was wondering if i could optimize it more, maybe someone struggled with that.

First of all I have table:

```
CREATE TABLE `site_url` (
    `id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `url_hash` CHAR(32) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `url` VARCHAR(2048) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `url_hash` (`url_hash`)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

where I store site URI (domain is in different table, but for purpose of this question id doesn't matter - I hope)

`url_hash` is MD5 calculated from `url`

It seems that all fields are in good length, indexes should be correct but there are a lat of data in it and I'm looking for more optimization.

Standard query looks like this:

```
select id from site_url where site_url.url_hash = MD5('something - often calculated in application rather than in mysql') and site_url.url = 'something - often calculated in application rather than in mysql'
```

describe gives:

```
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+----------+---------+-------+------+------------------------------------+
| id | select_type |  table   | type | possible_keys |   key    | key_len |  ref  | rows |               Extra                |
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+----------+---------+-------+------+------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | site_url | ref  | url_hash      | url_hash |      97 | const |    1 | Using index condition; Using where |
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+----------+---------+-------+------+------------------------------------+
```

But I'm wondering if I could help mysql doing that search. It must by InnoDB engine, I can't add key to `url` because of it's length

Friend of mine told me to short up hash to 16 chars, and write it as number. Will index on `BIGINT` be faster than on `char(32)`? Friend also suggested to do MD5 and take 16 first/last chars of it but I think it will make a lot more collisions.

What are your thoughts about it?

Comment: You can shorten the `url_hash` to `binary(16)`. An integer won't be large enough to store the hash as number. That should give you some more space. Also, optimizing MySQL will help immensely. Look up your `innodb_buffer_pool_size` variable and google around to see what people are doing with it to turbocharge MySQL performance.

Comment: That is great idea, with less complications to handle in refactorization process. Just need to change 2 queries and field: INSERT`insert into site_url (url_hash,url) values (UNHEX(md5('/uri')),'/uri');` and SELECT: `SELECT id FROM site_url USE INDEX (url_hash) WHERE url_hash = UNHEX(md5('/uri')) AND url = '/uri';`

Comment: Exactly, also having you know to use unhex in MySQL is a breath of fresh air to be honest :) don't forget to optimize InnoDB if you haven't already .

Answer (score 1):

This is your query:

```
select id
from site_url
where site_url.url_hash = MD5('something - often calculated in application rather than in mysql') and
      site_url.url = 'something - often calculated in application rather than in mysql';
```

The best index for this query would be on `site_url(url_hash, url, id)`.  The caveat is that you might need to use a prefix unless you have the large prefix option set (see [innodb_large_prefix](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_large_prefix)).

Comment: thank's for reply currently i'm not sure if i can change  innodb_large_prefix variable, Your index seems to be best until You can create such long index

Answer (score 0):

If url_hash is md5 of url why you select by 2 keys?

```
select id from site_url where site_url.url_hash = MD5('something - often calculated in application rather than in mysql');
```

Actually you dont need seсond check of site_url.url;

But if you want, you can select by 2 fields with USE INDEX syntax:

```
select id from site_url USE INDEX (url_hash) where site_url.url_hash = MD5('something - often calculated in application rather than in mysql') and site_url.url = 'something - often calculated in application rather than in mysql');
```

Comment: I use 2 fields in where to be sure i don't have collision in md5 hash (same hash but different url)

Comment: Hmm. If you are not sure about md5 use sha2 with 256 characters.

Comment: I have a similar project with urls and so on. md5 and sha2 work fine for me, without collisions.

Comment: I want to use rather smaller key, than longer one

Comment: Ok. Then you can select by 2 fields, but with USE INDEX (url_hash)

Comment: I've never used `USE INDEX` will it be much faster (in Your experience) mysql is already `Using index condition; Using where` same if I add `USE INDEX`

Comment: USE INDEX will force mysql to use specified index(es). With 'USE INDEX' select will work a bit faster (CPU will not be used to determine which index to use).